# Symfony Form collection results in entity being set inside itself

Tags: symfony, doctrine, formbuilder

When using an entity in a collection, the entity is set on the property I'm calling.

This kind of makes sense, ProductType is saying "hey, you wanna change the Title? sure man, here's a list of those entities you wanted" - and on submit, it sets the entity as the title. So this doesn't look like the right way to achieve what I want (to assign n number of Products to a user), but it appears to be the recommended way:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

So I have User with a unidirectional ManyToMany relationship with Product:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product")
 */
protected $products;
```

The User form has a Collection, each of which is an Entity Field Type - User form type:

```
...
->add('products', 'collection', array('type'=>new ProductType()))
```

and in the ProductType I have:

```
$builder->add('title', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ThingsStuffBundle:product',
            'property' => 'title',
            'required'  => false,
            'empty_value' => 'product',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er
                    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->orderBy('p.title', 'ASC');
            },
        ));
```

Which works. Sort of. When I submit the form it appears that I'm updating the product title rather than using it as just a choice array.

Submitted data:

```
$userEntity->products[
    productEntity{
        id = 1,
        title = productEntity{
            id = 1,
            title = 'balls'
        }
    },
    productEntity{
        id = 2,
        title = productEntity{
            id = 2,
            title = 'suck'
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build this type of add / delete collection

```
->add('products', 'collection', array('type'=>new ProductType(),
'allow_add' => true,
'allow_delete' => true
))
```

And then in the ProductType:

```
$builder->add('product', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ThingsStuffBundle:product'
    ));
```

NOTE: This add / remove will work provided you add the corresponding frontend javascript as described in the documentation.
Think of a collection like a bag where you add or remove Products.